# Best way to find a match from large table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, memory-limit

The best way to find a match between a few columns in the Data Base

I'd like to do something like this:

If you find a match to $ a, display the ID of the row

I am debating between two ways:

1. Select the entire table and look for a match and keep them a Data Base and then present them to from the array
2. Or that each time it search for matching from the table

The problem is that each time I perform a query for all the table (very large table) there is a problem with memory limit

So I'm looking for a way that takes the least memory

Comment: A relation, an Index, MATCH (Fulltext Search), and a JOIN? And you should specify the Database you use.

Comment: Please provide an example of query.

Answer (score 0):

If all the data is in a single table, be sure that the data you are querying is indexed. This will ensure an 'optimal' search for your table.

In terms of memory, if you have an extremely large result set and slam the entire dataset into an array, you may run out of memory. To deal with this, you should page the data e.g. load some limited number results into the array for display, then present more data as the user asks for it.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, selecting limited results from the database is faster and less memory intensive than populating large arrays.  For a large table, be sure you only select the data you require.  You might be looking for something like

```
SELECT record_id FROM your_table WHERE your_table.your_column = '$a' LIMIT 1;
```

This will only return one record in your result set.